# change the array by task

Tags: swift, xcode

How to put the same, but positive, before each negative element of the array. Count the number of inserted elements

example:

```
var arrayInt:  [Int] = [22, 16, -39, 1, -200]
```

> result: `[22, 16, 39, -39, 1, 200, -200]`

what to use for-in or method .map or method .filter

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a relatively simple implementation:

```
let result: [Int] = arrayInt.reduce(into: []) { acc, item in
    if item < 0 {
        acc.append(-item)
    }
    acc.append(item)
}
```

`reduce` allows you to transform an array into an arbitrary type. In this case, you still want an `[Int]`, but you don't want to be constrained to the same number of elements (like `map` would do).

If you need the number of inserted elements:

```
let inserted = result.count - arrayInt.count
```

Note that you could also build this into the `result` by returning a tuple with a count instead of just an `[Int]`

Keep in mind this is not the only possible solution -- just a relatively straightforward one.

---

In response to the comments, you could also turn this into a one-liner with something like `flatMap`: `arrayInt.flatMap { $0 < 0 ? [-$0, $0] : [$0] }`

Comment: `abs` of a positive integer is a no-op, so you don't need this `if` statement. Further, you're using `reduce` to re-invent something that already exists: `map`. This can just be `let result = arrayInt.map { item in abs(item) }`, or simply, `let result = arrayInt.map(abs)`. See https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Don't%20abuse%20reduce.md

Comment: @Alexander but that's not at all what the question asks about, unless I'm completely misreading it. Check out the desired result.

Comment: @jnpdxooo my apologies, i misunderstood it. Looks like you can still use `flatMap`, though

Comment: @Alexander sure -- `arrayInt.flatMap { $0 < 0 ? [abs($0), $0] : [$0] }` would work, for example, but I considered that the above would probably be a little easier to understand for a beginner/novice programmer (see note of "Keep in mind...")